# Extract data before and after matching (BIG FILE )

Tags: unix, design-patterns, awk, sed, grep

I have got a big file ( arounf 80K lines ) 
my main goal is to find the patterns and pring for example 10 lines before and 10 lines after the pattern . 
the pattern accures multiple times across the file . 
using the grep command  :

```
grep -i <my_pattern>* -B 10 -A 10 <my_file>
```

i get only some of the data , i think it must be something related to the buffer size ....

i need a command ( grep , sed , awk ) that will handle all the matching 
and will print 10 line before and after the pattern ...

Example :

my patterns hides here :

```
a
b
c
pattern_234
c
b
a
a
b
c
pattern_567
c
b
a
```

this happens multiple times across the file . 
running this command :

```
grep -i pattern_* -B 3 -A 3 <my_file>
```

will get he right output :

```
a
b
c
c
b
a
a
b
c
c
b
```

it works but not full time 
if i have 80 patterns not all the 80 will be shown

Comment: 80K lines is nothing for grep and the only buffering it would need to do is for the 10 "before" lines in case of a match. Can you show us your pattern and a sample of input data you expect to match but don't?

Comment: jas i added Example section to the main message, hope it helps

Comment: Your sample output excludes the `pattern_*` lines.  Is that intentional?  Can you give us an example of when `grep` doesn't work?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your file size or buffering. There is something wrong with the way you are writing the regexp that you are asking grep to search with or some other misunderstanding you have about the way grep works. Try to come up with a small (i.e. less than 20 lines) sample input file that you can reproduce the problem with and edit your question to show that.

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue

```
awk -vn=4                     # pass the argument of context line count
  '{
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)        # store the past n lines in an indexed array
       p[i]=p[i+1];
     p[n+1]=$0
   } 

   /pattern/                  # if pattern matched
   {
     c=n+1;                   # set the counter to after match line count
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)        # print previously saved entries
       print p[i]
   } 
   c-->0'                     # print the lines after match until counter runs out
```

will print 4 lines before and 4 lines after the match of pattern, change the value of n as per your need.

if non-symmetric before/after you need two variables

```
awk -vb=2 -va=3 '{for(i=1;i<=b;i++) p[i]=p[i+1];p[b+1]=$0} /pattern/{c=a+1;for(i=1;i<=b;i++) print p[i]} c-->0'
```

Comment: hi kara, but if the before and after amount of lines is not equal ?
for example : print 5 lines before and 6 lines after the match ..

Comment: kara can you please give a prief examplanation to the awks example ... it will help me alot ... if you can please

Comment: This prints the pattern as well (I think that should be the default use case).  You can eliminate by changing the for loop terminal condition.  The code is not robust to handle overlapping context for different patterns.